How can I compare a value in one column to all values that are BEFORE it in another column?
My DataFrame:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'high': [100, 102, 120, 150, 125, 115],
        'target': [99, 105, 118, 108, 140, 141]
    }
)

Expected output is creating column x:
   high  target    x
0   100      99    99
1   102     105    99
2   120     118    118
3   150     108    118
4   125     140    118
5   115     141    108

I explain it row by row. I start from row 1 because it is easier to explain.
102 should be compared with all of the targets that are before it or on the same row. That is, 102 should be compared with 99 and 105. Of these two values, I want to find the maximum value that is LESS or EQUAL than 102. The max value is 99. So this value is chosen for x.
For row 2, 120 should be compared with 99, 105 and 118. Again the same logic applies and the value for x is 105.
For row 3, 150 should be compared with 99, 105, 118 and 108. All of these values are less than 150 but the maximum value is 118.
This is my attempt that failed:
import numpy as np
bins = df.target.sort_values(ascending=True).to_list()
bins = bins + [np.inf]
labels = bins[:-1]
df['x'] = pd.cut(df.high, include_lowest=True, right=False, labels=labels, bins=bins)


What is number of rows in your real data?

@jezrael Something around 70k,

a more performant option would be to run the for loop in a lower level language(or jit compiled - numba)

@sammywemmy Thanks for your suggestion. Can you post your comment as an answer with a sample code or hint?

Numpy solution with broadcasting - comapre for less or equal with select only rows above existing values by another mask m2, if not match replace by nan and get maximal by numpy.nanmax:
t = df['target'].to_numpy()
h = df['high'].to_numpy()

m1 = np.arange(len(t))[:,None] >= np.arange(len(t))
m2 = t <= h[:, None]

df['x'] = np.nanmax(np.where(m1 & m2, t, np.nan), axis=1)
print (df)
   high  target      x
0   100      99   99.0
1   102     105   99.0
2   120     118  118.0
3   150     108  118.0
4   125     140  118.0
5   115     141  108.0

How it working:
print (m1)
[[ True False False False False False]
 [ True  True False False False False]
 [ True  True  True False False False]
 [ True  True  True  True False False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True]]

print (m2)
[[ True False False False False False]
 [ True False False False False False]
 [ True  True  True  True False False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True False False]
 [ True  True False  True False False]]

print (m1 & m2)
[[ True False False False False False]
 [ True False False False False False]
 [ True  True  True False False False]
 [ True  True  True  True False False]
 [ True  True  True  True False False]
 [ True  True False  True False False]]


print (np.where(m1 & m2, t, np.nan))
[[ 99.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
 [ 99.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
 [ 99. 105. 118.  nan  nan  nan]
 [ 99. 105. 118. 108.  nan  nan]
 [ 99. 105. 118. 108.  nan  nan]
 [ 99. 105.  nan 108.  nan  nan]]

print (np.nanmax(np.where(m1 & m2, t, np.nan), axis=1))
[ 99.  99. 118. 118. 118. 108.]


This answer is obviously more efficient than my answer(loop). I recommend questioner  to choose this answer.  One thing to note is that there is a RAM issue. I'm a collab user and it won't run beyond 50k lines dataframe.

@PandaKim - yop, absolutely agree, if very large data there should be RAM problem.

this is one way to go about it, using numba:
# pip install numba
import numba

@numba.njit()
def max_val(arr1, arr2, result):
    lo = 0
    hi = arr1.size
    max_value = arr2[0]
    start = 0
    while lo < hi:
        value = arr1[lo]
        if max_value > value:
            max_value = arr2[0]
            start = 0
            for n in range(start, lo+1):
                val = arr2[n]
                if val>value:
                    continue
                if val > max_value:
                    max_value = val
                    start = n
            result[lo]=max_value
            lo += 1
    return result


t = df['target'].to_numpy()
h = df['high'].to_numpy()
result = np.empty(t.size, dtype=t.dtype)
df['x'] = max_val(arr1=h,arr2=t,result=result)
df
   high  target    x
0   100      99   99
1   102     105   99
2   120     118  118
3   150     108  118
4   125     140  118
5   115     141  108

This should guide you in making a more performant loop (use unsigned integers for indexing, parallelize maybe, use a dedicated lower level language, ...)

df['x'] = [
    df.loc[:i, 'target']
      .where(lambda x: x.le(df.loc[i, 'high']))
      .max()
    for i in df.index
]


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'high': [100, 102, 120, 150, 125, 115],
        'target': [99, 105, 118, 108, 140, 141]
    }
)

# Convert columns to numpy arrays
t = df['target'].to_numpy()
h = df['high'].to_numpy()

# Step 1: Create a full comparison matrix
comparison_matrix = t <= h[:, None]
print("Comparison Matrix:")
print(comparison_matrix)
'''
Comparison Matrix:
[[ True False False False False False]
 [ True False False False False False]
 [ True  True  True  True False False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True False False]
 [ True  True False  True False False]]

'''
# Step 2: Create a lower triangular mask
lower_triangular_mask = np.tril(comparison_matrix)
print("\nLower Triangular Mask:")
print(lower_triangular_mask)
'''

Lower Triangular Mask:
[[ True False False False False False]
 [ True False False False False False]
 [ True  True  True False False False]
 [ True  True  True  True False False]
 [ True  True  True  True False False]
 [ True  True False  True False False]]
'''

# Step 3: Apply the mask and replace False values with NaN
masked_targets = np.where(lower_triangular_mask, t, np.nan)
print("\nMasked Targets:")
print(masked_targets)
'''
Masked Targets:
[[ 99.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
 [ 99.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
 [ 99. 105. 118.  nan  nan  nan]
 [ 99. 105. 118. 108.  nan  nan]
 [ 99. 105. 118. 108.  nan  nan]
 [ 99. 105.  nan 108.  nan  nan]]
'''
# Step 4: Find the maximum value in each row, ignoring NaNs
df['x'] = np.nanmax(masked_targets, axis=1)
print("\nDataFrame with 'x' column:")
print(df)
'''
DataFrame with 'x' column:

   high  target      x
0   100      99   99.0
1   102     105   99.0
2   120     118  118.0
3   150     108  118.0
4   125     140  118.0
5   115     141  108.0
'''

